# react js : multiple components in a file throws an error ! I'm using react js using CDN

Tags: reactjs

when i create more than one component in my react js file its showing the following error

**Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined**

i use reactJS using the CDN. Yarn is installed. I use Babel to convert jsx into es15.

Please help me with the error. Since im new to React im  not used to the errors and im stuck at the beginning stage itsels...

this is my code

```js
var myList = ['hello'];

var onFormSubmit = function onFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var item = e.target.elements.input.value;

    if (item) {
        myList.push(item);
        e.target.elements.input.value = "";
        //render template function
        console.log(myList);
        renderTemplate();
    }
};

class NavBar extends React.Component() {
    render() {
        return(
            <nav><h1>My App</h1></nav>
        )
    }
}

class Form extends React.Component() {
    render() {
        return(
            <form onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
                <input type="text" name="input" />
                <button>Add item</button>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

class List extends React.Component() {
    render() {
        return(
            myList.map((item) => {
                <p>{item}</p>
            })
        )
    }
}

class MyApp extends React.Component() {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <NavBar />
                <Form />
                <List />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

var appRoot = document.getElementById('app');

var renderTemplate = () => {
    ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, appRoot);
}

renderTemplate();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`class Something extends React.Component { }` without the parenthesis should work for you since you are referencing the class, not calling a new instance of it.